# RestAPi calling using Java code, need to write connections in separate code

Tags: java

I wanted to hide HTTP connections by using another class for HTTP connections and wanted to reduce this code. Can anybody help me doing this?

```
public class ExportGroups {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            String username = "username";
            String password = "pass@word123";
            String userPassword = username + ":" + password;
            String encoding = new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder().encode(userPassword.getBytes());

            URL url = new URL("https://AgilePointServer/Extension/ExportGroups");
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + encoding);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
            String input = "{\"groupNames\": [\"Accounts Payable\"]}";
            OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
            os.write(input.getBytes());
            os.flush();
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((conn.getInputStream())));

            String output;
            System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
            while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(output);
            }
            conn.disconnect();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the problem with the code...?

Comment: So what is your *specific* question? Please read the [tour] and the [help] for an introduction and a more detailed explanation of StackOverflow.

Comment: I wanted to optimize code and my code should hide http connections which should be called from another program , i need to wrap these connections in one class and wanted to call using a method

Comment: Use http framework for that. Apache HttpClient, OkHttpClient, Retrofit.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you want a class named "ConnectionFactory" which handles the connection initialization. It can have a method "createConnection" with username, password, URL as its arguments, and it initializes the HttpURLConnection then returns the connection. When you want to create a connection, you call

```
HttpURLConnection connection = ConnectionFactory.createConnection(username, password, url);
```

Comment: Yeah i've tried like what u said but its missing some functionality, basically I'm new to java, that's y struggling.

Comment: public string ExportGroups()
        {
            String URL = " “https://AgilePointServer/Extension/ExportGroups"";
            JSONObject postData = new JSONObject();
    postData.put("groupNames", "GroupName");

            HTTPOperations ops = new HTTPOperations(domain, this.userName, password,userPassword);

            return ops.POSTMethod(URL, postData.toString());
        }
}

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend using Retrofit.
You would only need to declare an interface, and let retrofit implement it.
Retrofit handles lots of things for you out of the box.

Examples can be found [here](https://square.github.io/retrofit/).